# JQuery Validate Text Box value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to validate the text box to allow only numbers. The problem is, it allows shift + special characters.
I've used the similar code for the name validation except few changes, but it doesn't allow any special characters. I'm confused.My code is

```
if(e.keyCode==46 || e.keyCode==8|| e.keyCode==9 || e.keyCode==37 || e.keyCode==39)
{
// do nothing allow
}
else if(e.keyCode>=48 && e.keyCode<=57)
{
// do nothing allow
}
else
{
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cH3zP/). On the fiddle the first input box didn't allow special characters like `@,#,$,%`. But the second allows special characters. I checked for the special characters in `If` statement. Is my logic correct? Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I think it's ok. However you should server side check the values you get from the user. Javascript on a browser can be turned off and consequently a malicious user can send you values that compromise your logic. So you must check them server side before they will be stored in a db.

Comment: In HTML5 you can use the pattern attribute which might be simpler http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: If I removed the `e.keyCode>=48 && e.keyCode<=57` and check for other characters, it doesn't allow shift key. Clearly the problem is in `e.keyCode>=48 && e.keyCode<=57`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:Try

http://jsfiddle.net/cH3zP/6/

```
var schk=0;
$('#phone').keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode==16)
{
    schk=0;
}
});
$('#phone').keydown(function(e){
if(e.keyCode==16)
{
    schk=1;
}
});
```

What i m doing in my code is when user presses down the button i just change the value of global variable `schk` to `1`.As long as user keep it pressed it will remain `1`.

when user leaves the shift key it is again initialized to `0` allowing its entry.

**Why work for 1st input and not for 2nd in Question fiddle?**

In your first input box you are not allowing numbers to display. shift+1 fires the same key code as when you press 1.So if you type 1 or ! the key code will be same `49`.

Comment: If you explain why, then I'll +1 this

Comment: What is the error in my code? and why that was not working and how your's is working? how it differs from mine?

Answer (score 0):

here is the updated code

```
var reg = new RegExp('^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$');
$('#phone')
.keydown(function(evt){
    var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    if (evt.keyCode == 46 || evt.keyCode == 8 || evt.keyCode == 9 || evt.keyCode == 27 || evt.keyCode == 13 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (evt.keyCode == 65 && evt.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (evt.keyCode >= 35 && evt.keyCode <= 39) || charCode == 46) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        else if (!reg.test(charStr)) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I think changing your first event binding function from `keydown` to `keypress` solves the problem:

See http://jsfiddle.net/cH3zP/5/

```
$('#phone').keypress(function(e){
if(e.keyCode==46 || e.keyCode==8|| e.keyCode==9 || e.keyCode==37 || e.keyCode==39)
{
// do nothing allow
}
else if(e.keyCode>=48 && e.keyCode<=57)
{
// do nothing allow
}
else
{
    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

Comment: It doesnt display anything

Comment: @Zword doesn't display anything? the link? I just checked it and I can type the values in the text fields as the original question requested..

Comment: type in second input box.you added keypress to second input not first

Comment: @ling.s If i understood your question right, you wanted the first field to only allow character inputs and the second to only allow numeric inputs. With the `keypress` to the second input, it allows only numeric inputs for me in that input, the first is still free to do any non-numeric inputs... so I'm not sure what you mean by everything is locked...

Comment: block second input from entering special characters {!,@,#...}

Comment: @Zword right, and in the fiddle I just posted, you can't entire the special characters in the second input, only numerals

Comment: In your fiddle, i'm unable to type numbers itself

Comment: @ling.s why dont you check my script.Isnt your problem solved.

Comment: @Zword chrome, latest version

Comment: @ling.s are you importing proper js library in your actual page? bcos if it works in fiddle it must work directly also.

Comment: If I made any mistake on importing,  then how the name validation works?